# list all suburls and check if broken in python

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a website developped in django, which consist of around 25000 suburls.
I need something to list all the urls in website and check if the links are broken periodically so i prefer to do something that i can run as a script.

Which method should i follow? Any idea ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [show-urls](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/show_urls.py) command in [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/) as a starting point. ([documentation](http://django-extensions.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_extensions.html?highlight=show_urls))

```
python manage.py show_urls
```

Answer (score 11):

Here is an improved class based on excellent @sneawo answer. Features include:

- automatic loading of all urlconfs based on `settings.ROOT_URLCONF`;
- recursive loading of included urlconfs;
- testing url patterns that expect keyword parameters (via default parameters);
- testing for different http codes;
- testing urls that work only for logged in users.

Improvements are welcome.

```
    from django import test
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
    from django.conf import settings
    import importlib

    class UrlsTest(test.TestCase):

        def test_responses(self, allowed_http_codes=[200, 302, 405],
                credentials={}, logout_url="", default_kwargs={}, quiet=False):
            """
            Test all pattern in root urlconf and included ones.
            Do GET requests only.
            A pattern is skipped if any of the conditions applies:
                - pattern has no name in urlconf
                - pattern expects any positinal parameters
                - pattern expects keyword parameters that are not specified in @default_kwargs
            If response code is not in @allowed_http_codes, fail the test.
            if @credentials dict is specified (e.g. username and password),
                login before run tests.
            If @logout_url is specified, then check if we accidentally logged out
                the client while testing, and login again
            Specify @default_kwargs to be used for patterns that expect keyword parameters,
                e.g. if you specify default_kwargs={'username': 'testuser'}, then
                for pattern url(r'^accounts/(?P<username>[\.\w-]+)/$' 
                the url /accounts/testuser/ will be tested.
            If @quiet=False, print all the urls checked. If status code of the response is not 200,
                print the status code.
            """
            module = importlib.import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)
            if credentials:
                self.client.login(**credentials)
            def check_urls(urlpatterns, prefix=''):
                for pattern in urlpatterns:
                    if hasattr(pattern, 'url_patterns'):
                        # this is an included urlconf
                        new_prefix = prefix
                        if pattern.namespace:
                            new_prefix = prefix + (":" if prefix else "") + pattern.namespace
                        check_urls(pattern.url_patterns, prefix=new_prefix)
                    params = {}
                    skip = False
                    regex = pattern.regex
                    if regex.groups > 0:
                        # the url expects parameters
                        # use default_kwargs supplied
                        if regex.groups > len(regex.groupindex.keys()) \
                            or set(regex.groupindex.keys()) - set(default_kwargs.keys()):
                            # there are positional parameters OR
                            # keyword parameters that are not supplied in default_kwargs
                            # so we skip the url
                            skip = True
                        else:
                            for key in set(default_kwargs.keys()) & set(regex.groupindex.keys()):
                                params[key] = default_kwargs[key]
                    if hasattr(pattern, "name") and pattern.name:
                        name = pattern.name
                    else:
                        # if pattern has no name, skip it
                        skip = True
                        name = ""
                    fullname = (prefix + ":" + name) if prefix else name
                    if not skip:
                        url = reverse(fullname, kwargs=params)
                        response = self.client.get(url)
                        self.assertIn(response.status_code, allowed_http_codes)
                        # print status code if it is not 200
                        status = "" if response.status_code == 200 else str(response.status_code) + " "
                        if not quiet:
                            print(status + url)
                        if url == logout_url and credentials:
                            # if we just tested logout, then login again
                            self.client.login(**credentials)
                    else:
                        if not quiet:
                            print("SKIP " + regex.pattern + " " + fullname)
            check_urls(module.urlpatterns)
```

Answer (score 4):

For simple urls without parameters, you can use such test:

```
from django import test
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from foo.urls import urlpatterns

class UrlsTest(test.TestCase):

    def test_responses(self):
        for url in urlpatterns:
            response = self.client.get(reverse(url.name))
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

In Django 2.2.x, I had to use this slightly modified version of @sneawo's excellent answer:

```py
from django import test
from django.urls import reverse, URLPattern

from myapp.urls import urlpatterns


class MyAppUrlsTest(test.SimpleTestCase):

    def test_responses(self):
        for url in urlpatterns:
            # For now, perform only GET requests and ignore URLs that need arguments.
            if not isinstance(url, URLPattern) or url.pattern.regex.groups or not url.name:
                continue
            urlpath = reverse(url.name)
            response = self.client.get(urlpath, follow=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Note that I'm also accounting for views that require arguments by just ignoring them. For my specific, simplistic use case, this also lets me exclude views by not giving them a `name` in my `urlpatterns`.

Also see https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5500#issue-146618375.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to add a logger like [Sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) (with [Raven](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html)) and add the contributed [404 middleware](http://raven.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config/django.html#logging) (or simply write your own custom 404 handler)

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are already uploaded to a Web server, a zero-coding solution is to use the free [W3C Link Checker](http://validator.w3.org/checklink).  It will try every link it finds in a page and provide a nice summary.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken a slightly different approach than the one using `reverse`, instead actually loading the sites and looking for all 'hrefs', then following all of those etc. The code below prints all the calls as a hierarchy. Currently it asserts the response code 200 (after following links), if you're testing 25000 subsites it probably makes sense to just log the response codes and then search the output.

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.test.testcases import TestCase
import re
from urlparse import urlsplit, urljoin

class GenericTestCase( TestCase ):
    fixtures = []

    def test_links( self ):
        self.p1 = re.compile( r'href="([^"]*)"' )
        self.p2 = re.compile( r"href='([^']*)'" )
        self.visited_urls = set()
        self.visit( '/', 0 )

    def visit( self, url, depth ):
        print( '-' * depth + url ),
        self.visited_urls.add( url )
        response = self.client.get( url, follow=True )
        if response.redirect_chain:
            url = urlsplit( response.redirect_chain[-1][0] ).path
            print( ' => ' + url )
            if url in self.visited_urls:
                return
            self.visited_urls.add( url )
        else:
            print( '' )

        self.assertEquals( response.status_code, 200 )

        refs = self.get_refs( response.content )
        for relative_url in refs:
            absolute_url = urljoin( url, relative_url )
            if not self.skip_url( absolute_url, relative_url ):
                self.visit( absolute_url, depth + 1 )

    def skip_url( self, absolute_url, relative_url ):
        return absolute_url in self.visited_urls \
            or  ':' in absolute_url \
            or absolute_url.startswith( settings.STATIC_URL ) \
            or relative_url.startswith( '#' )

    def get_refs( self, text ):
        urls = set()
        urls.update( self.p1.findall( text ) )
        urls.update( self.p2.findall( text ) )
        return urls
```